# Can not reach to SonarQube server using gitlab CI in gradle project

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, gitlab-ci

Using gitlab CI, can not reach to sonarqube server.

I have opened the firewall on port 9000 but can not solve the problem. Also try with replacing "localhost" with ip address

The yml file for gitlab ci -

```
variables:
 SONAR_URL: "http://localhost:9000"
 SONAR_LOGIN: "admin"
 SONAR_PASSWORD: "admin"

image: gradle:latest

build:
 stage: build
 script:
  - bash ./gradlew sonarqube -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_URL -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_LOGIN -Dsonar.password=$SONAR_PASSWORD
 only:
  - master
```

The output from Gradle:

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
> Task :compileJava
> Task :compileGroovy NO-SOURCE
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes
> Task :compileTestJava
> Task :compileTestGroovy NO-SOURCE
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses
> Task :test

> Task :sonarqube FAILED
SonarQube server [http://localhost:9000] can not be reached

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.
> Unable to execute SonarQube

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 28s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed
```

Comment: Is SonarQube really running on the same server as your Gitlab CI Runner?

Comment: No. Got the solution. But is it possible if Gitlab CI Runner and SonarQube in same network?

Comment: Please post your solution to assist anyone who has a similar issue to you!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your follow on question, but it is possible to run Gitlab runner and SonarQube on different hosts on the same network.

Comment: Actually the SonarQube server and Gitlab CI runner was not in same server or network.

Comment: I have the same issue. I use gitlab on gitlab.com and sonar on local machine. How I can resolve?